# Can you use the lapply() function to alter the value of input?

Tags: r, loops, lapply

I was wondering whether it is possible to use the lapply() function to alter the value of the input, similar to:

```
a1<-runif(100)
a2<-function(i){
a1[i]<-a1[i-1]*a1[i];a1[i]
}
a3<-lapply(2:100,a2)
```

I'm looking for something akin to a for() loop, but using the lapply() infrastructure. I haven't been able to get rapply() to do this.

The reason is that the "real" a2 function is a difficult function that only needs to be evaluated if the value of a1[i-1] meets some criteria.

re-phrasing: so i'm trying to replace the for() in the code below by a lapply()-type thing:

```
    a1<-runif(100)
    a2<-function(i, a1){
        a1[i]<-a1[i-1]*2
        a1[i]
    }
    a3<-as.numeric(lapply(2:100, a2, a1=a1))
#compare the output of a3 with that of a1 after the recursive loop
    a2<-a1 #saved for comparison
    for(i in 2:length(a1)){
        a1[i]<-a1[i-1]*2
    }
cbind(a1[2:100],a3)
#actually this is would be like writting a lapply() version of the cumprod() function
cbind(a1,cumprod(a2))
```

The R mailing list has advised looking unto the Reduce() function....as in:

```
a1<-runif(100)
cadd<-function(x) Reduce("*", x, accumulate = TRUE)
cadd(a1)
```

which gives the same result as cumprod(a1)...but is even slower than the loop:

```
a1<-runif(100000)
cadd<-function(x) Reduce("*", x, accumulate = TRUE)
looop<-function(a1){
j<-length(a1)
    for(i in 2:j){
        a1[i]<-a1[i-1]*a1[i]
    }
a1
}

> system.time(cadd(a1))
   user  system elapsed 
  1.344   0.004   1.353 
> system.time(cumprod(a1))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.004   0.000   0.002 
> system.time(loop(a1))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.772   0.000   0.775 
>
```

Any idea ?

Comment: I don't think I  follow what you want to do. Does a1[i] (what you are calculating) depend on a1[i-1]? If it does, I think it's best to use loops. If not, it would be best to subset the vector and do the function in that part.

Comment: Should these be equivalent in your last line above: cbind(a1,cumprod(a2))?  As far as I can tell, they don't match.

Comment: Shane: that's the problem: the looop() function (see post) gives the same result as cumprod....but the lapply() version does not. 

I want to recursively apply a function (more complicated than multiplication) which uses the value of the previous evaluation on a vector...and can't find a way to avoid the loop

Comment: I was actually referring to your loop output.

Comment: Is your goal to speed up your program, or to make it more readable?  If you want to speed it up, your primary option is going to be to use C/C++.  See the other question that I linked below regarding recursive sequences in R.

Comment: Shane: thanks for the link...right on target :)
How do i mark a question as solved ?

Comment: There's a little checkbox below the voting icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edit:* Following your clarification: no, I don't believe that you can use an apply function to do something recursively like that.  The whole point of an apply function is that it applies across the vector/matrix at the same time.

You may also want to [look at this related question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478758/optimizing-the-computation-of-a-recursive-sequence).

*My old answer:*

Try this:

```
a1<-runif(100)
a2<-function(i, a1){
    a1[i]<-a1[i-1]*a1[i]
    a1[i]
}
a3 <- as.numeric(lapply(2:100, a2, a1=a1))
```

Unlike a `for` loop, you need to pass in a reference to anything that you need within an `lapply`.  The return is also a list, so you need to cast it back into whatever form you want.

You might also want to look at the plyr package for easy ways to do this kind of thing.

Beyond that, you can do your operation without a loop:

```
a3 <- a1[-length(a1)] * a1[-1]
```

In other words, these statements are completely equivalent:

```
> all((a1[-length(a1)] * a1[-1]) == as.numeric(lapply(2:100, a2, a1=a1)))
[1] TRUE
```

But the first version is preferable since it has no iterations.