# how to avoid this loop in R (rapply ? lapply ?)

Tags: r, loops, lapply, mapply

I'm trying to replace this loop by a symple command without any succes (lapply ? rapply ? mapply ?). Maybe it's a rare case in R that loops are really needed ?

```
n <- 10
x <- vector(mode="numeric", length=n)

for(i in 2:n) {
    x[i] <- x[i-1]+runif(1)
}
```

my question was badly formulated. The responses helped me understand that what I actually need is to access the values ​​of a vector into a function. With a loop that is simple for any function "f" we can be calculated:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4)
for(i in 2:4) {
    x[i] <- f(x[i-1])
}
```

Maybe the only way is global variables ?

Comment: I have found this thread that explain well the problem and point to a solution:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559724/can-you-use-the-lapply-function-to-alter-the-value-of-input?rq=1  Thank you for all answers.

Answer (score 3):

For your exact question, you don't need a `apply` function at all, because you can vectorise it with `cumsum`:

Your code:

```
n <- 10
x <- vector(mode="numeric", length=n)

set.seed(1)
for(i in 2:n) {
  x[i] <- x[i-1]+runif(1)
}
x
[1] 0.0000000 0.2655087 0.6376326 1.2104859 2.1186937 2.3203756 3.2187653 4.1634406 4.8242384
[10] 5.4533524
```

My code:

```
set.seed(1)
c(0, cumsum(runif(n-1)))
 [1] 0.0000000 0.2655087 0.6376326 1.2104859 2.1186937 2.3203756 3.2187653 4.1634406 4.8242384
[10] 5.4533524
```

Comment: Thank you, yes cumsum is the perfect answer, I'm sorry my exemple code was to simple , I need to add x[i] = x[i-1]+afunction(x[i-1])...

Comment: @LeonEspinosa What is `afunction()` in your case?

Comment: sorry, any function that will take as parameter "x[i-1]"  like x[i] = x[i-1]+x[i-1]^2

Comment: @LeonEspinosa you've gotten four good answers to your original post and you've commented on each one of them that they're not good for you because your actual problem is not represented by your original post. Please edit your original post to represent what you really need.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cumsum`. So just add zero to the cumulative sum of your random variables vector

```
n <- 10
x <- vector(mode="numeric", length=n)
rData <- runif(9)
for(i in 2:n) {
  x[i] <- x[i-1]+rData[i-1]
}

identical(c(0, cumsum(rData)), x)

> identical(c(0, cumsum(rData)), x)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: thank you ! my code example was too simply... the "runif" part will be replace by more complexe function that depends on the x[i-1] value

Answer (score 1):

You can use sapply like

```
c(x[1],(sapply(x,function(a){a+runif(1)})[-length(x)]))
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems that this is not reproducing the loop solution, the resuslt with the loop is an increasing sequence were x[i] = x[i-1] + something. This sapply command yield a random set with offset values (= initial x values). If I'm right lapply and sapply build the result value in the memory before to yield the "whole" result so I can not acces to intermediate values as x[i-1]

Answer (score 1):

Another way of achieving this, is to use `Reduce`:

```
f <- function(a, b) a + runif(1)  
x <- Reduce(f, x, accumulate = TRUE)
```

(just suggesting this as a generalisable alternative; the `cumsum` way in other answers is way faster)

Comment: Thank you, yes it works perfect. But could the function f acces to each value of x ? exemple f <- function(a) a[length(a)]+a[length(a)-1]^2 it gaves an error because for length(a)-1 = 0 (first element of x) and I don't know how to prevent it

Comment: Are you looking for `Reduce(function(a, b) a ^ 2 + b, 1:10, accumulate = T)`? Basically you have to think of `b` as taking the value `x[i]` and `a` the value from the function applied to the previous entries of `x` iteratively. So no need to call `length(a)` just `a` will do. `f` is a function of two "scalars" (or vectors of length 1 if you prefer, to use the R language).

Comment: About your question whether `f` can access all values of `x` the answer is no in this case, since this is not how `Reduce` works. `Reduce` takes a function of 2 arguments and applies it iteratively to the vector. If you need to access all individual entries of `x` you need to come up with another way (possibly using `Map`, but still not sure what your function looks like and what you are trying to do exactly).

Comment: Yes I'm afraid that I need is exactly acces to the values of the vector in the function that will be applied. Maybe a global variable could be a workaround

Comment: I think using a global variable is not a very good idea in most cases. So you have a function `f` and a vector `x` of length `N` and you want to obtain a vector `(f(x[1]), f(c(x[1], x[2])), ..., f(c(x[1],...,x[N]))`, right? How about you write a function `g <- function(n, v) f(v[1:n])` and then use `lapply(1:N, g, v = x)`? Probably not the most efficient way of doing it though and I think if you were more precise about what `f` looks like then you could speed things up (like using `cumsum` as others suggested for the example you gave).

Comment: I agree, I start a project to model different kinds of walk (random, direct, oriented, etc.) so my first step was to investigate how to obtain a sequence of positions that depends on the previous steps... but my question was badly formulate I will try to fix better the exact problem and post it in another way... thank you for all suggestions